# Android changing background of imageview in an custom dialog doesnt work

Tags: android, dialog, imageview

Here is my code :

```
private void setWeatherDialogInfoAndIcons(){
    WeatherGoogle weather = WeatherGoogle.getInstance("istanbul");
    String iconsPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/arla/images/hava/";
    String[] allData = weather.getCityData().split("<>");

    currentImage = (ImageView) customDialog.findViewById(R.id.imageViewcurrentWeatherImage );
    currentInfo  = (TextView) customDialog.findViewById( R.id.textViewCurrentInfo )  ;
    currentInfo.setText( allData[0] +"\n"+allData[1]+"\n"+allData[2]+"\n"+allData[3] );

    currentImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.air);
    currentImage.setBackgroundDrawable( UiHelper.getDrawableFromSdcard(iconsPath + weather.getIconName(0)) );

    int j = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < dayInfos.size() ; i++) {
        dayInfos.get(i).setText( allData[j] +"\nMin  : "+ allData[j+1] +"\nMaks: "+ allData[j+2] 
                + "\n" + allData[j+3]   );
        j+=4;
    }

}
```

I can change the texts of textviews but when i want to set the background of imageviev(currentImage) it doesnt work , it shows the dialog but there is no background in **Imageview**.

```
 currentImage.setBackgroundDrawable( UiHelper.getDrawableFromSdcard(iconsPath + weather.getIconName(0)) );
```

I am sure that my method **getDrawableFromSdcard** works because i used it somewhere else in my code lastly i checked png icon and its path. So what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
currentImage.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.air));
```

From SDcard :

```
Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file_path");
imageView.setImageBitmap(picture);
```

Try it. Good luck!

Comment: It cant help me because I m trying to get drawable from sdcard !

Answer (score -1):

The method `setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background)` is deprecated. You have to use `setBackground(Drawable)` instead. See the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

Comment: I m developing app for device that has version 2.3.1 Api level 9.

Comment: setBackground is only available for api 16+ and so more then 95% of devices will crash if it is not checked before.